# How can I prevent update-grub from overwriting existing bootloader?

Tags: kali-linux, grub2, uefi, boot-loader

I use openSUSE Tumbleweed as my primary distribution, and Kali Linux as my secondary distribution in my laptop. I installed Kali Linux first; after that, I installed Tumbleweed which removed Kali Linux's grub and installed its own and added a boot entry for Kali Linux. I am afraid that after a kernel update, Kali Linux will run `update-grub` which may replace Tumbleweed's Grub with its own. I don't want that to happen, because Tumbleweed made a boot entry that allows me to boot from snapshots.

I am running an EFI setup.

Will running `update-grub` from Kali Linux remove Tumbleweed's Grub? If so, how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503417/how-to-prevent-ubuntu-from-overwriting-grub-bootloader-after-update) (not an exact duplicate, but close) should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new `grub2` or (as called in debian package management) `grub-pc` does update the bootloader if there is some change in the `grub-pc` package itself. That is to ensure that the binary part of the bootloader inside the /boot/grub directory are matched by the binary (the bootloader) which loads such plug-ins.

The correct solution is to configure the kali Linux grub to not update anything.

That could be done, as [this answer explain](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503417/how-to-prevent-ubuntu-from-overwriting-grub-bootloader-after-update) with (from inside Kali Linux):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

That will remove the updates from Kali linux.

Then, reboot to Tumbleweed and make sure it is updating grub. Which, at this point, will be the only one updating the boot loader.

Answer (score 1):

`update-grub` only updates grub.cfg

it will not run grub-install to replace the bootloader.

Comment: That **was** true of the older grub. But the question is tagged grub2 which does update the boot-loader (most of the time). So, no, this answer is not the whole truth.

Comment: @Arrow I _think_ what you mean is that my statement is the best sort of correct ("technically").  https://askubuntu.com/a/167768/20709  But `dpkg-reconfigure` would re-install it to the configured location.  I'm surprised that package updates do the same, but it's still plausible.  So assuming Kali is a derivative of Debian, your question comment is a better answer.

Comment: @Arrow I am going to follow the answer you referred, but after every kali linux kernel update will I have to run grub2-mkconfig from Tumbleweed?

Comment: The answer you link to is about the difference of the program name, not of what the program does. There is a big diference beetween grub and grub-pc. And yes, grub-pc does update the bootloader when the grub-pc version change.

Comment: @RHF what I need to say is too long for a comment, so, I posted an answer. But, to be very clear, The change is a **one time** only change. After it Kali's grub-pc will **not** update the bootloader leaving any other distribution to do the updating. And it does need to be updated when grup-pc makes changes that are not backward compatible.